# Difference between reference value and primitive value

Tags: java, primitive, primitive-types

Objects are reference type, which means reference type of an object holds the address in memory where actual data is stored.

For example

```
Integer object = new Integer(3);
```

But if we talk about primitive types, like `int number = 3;` then where `number` is pointing to ?

Is it itself in memory ? What it holds ?

Answer (score 2):

In java we have something called stack memory where all the primitive are stored.

There was a similar discussion which you can visit by following this link

[Where does the JVM store primitive variables?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3698078/where-does-the-jvm-store-primitive-variables)

Answer (score 0):

Primitive data types are stored in the **stack**, while reference data types are stored in the **heap**.

So when you say `int number=3;`, a 32-bit long (by default) chunk of memory on the stack is put aside. This chunk holds the value 3 and can be identified by the variable name *number*.

But when you say `Integer object = new Integer(3);`, the memory is assigned from the heap, and a **reference** is created to that chunk of memory. This memory is for the `object` instance of the `Integer` class, so it gets more memory than your `int number`. This is because the `Integer` class wraps inside it, not just a **primitive int** but also some other methods that can be used on its instances.

You should also understand that when you pass a primitive data type to an assignment statement or to a function, it is **passed by copy** so the changes don't reflect on the original variable. But if you pass the Integer object, it is **passed by reference**, i.e. a pointer to that large chunk of memory on the heap, so the changes are visible on the actual object.

Comment: *"But if you pass the Integer object, it is passed by reference... "* ... more accurately, the reference itself is passed by value to a method.  Therefore, reassigning a new object reference to the argument variable in the method will have no effect on the reference variable in the calling code.

Answer (score 0):

Primitive type can be stored in both stack and heap depending on its scope.

In your example given above, `number`is just a chunk of memory holding binary value representation of number 3, depending if it is a local variable or an instance variable, it can be stored in either stack or heap.

See the post [Do Java primitives go on the Stack or the Heap?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3646632/do-java-primitives-go-on-the-stack-or-the-heap) and [Stack Memory and Heap Space in Java](https://www.baeldung.com/java-stack-heap)

```
class Person {
    int pid;
    String name;

    // constructor, setters/getters
}

public class Driver {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int id = 23;
        String pName = "Jon";
        Person p = null;
        p = new Person(id, pName); // primitive in heap
    }
}
```

Example of primitive type in heap: When `p` is assigned with `Person` constructor, a new instance of `Person` class is created in heap memory, which has a memory chunk holding value of 23.